# Can a dual-band wifi extender be used with a single band router?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

And does it provide any advantages over a single-band wifi extender?
Or will the dual-band nature of the wifi extender be moot?

I have an Actiontec MI424WR wifi router (which is single-band), and I'm deciding which wifi extender to get. My house is too large to directly connect a second router to the Actiontec MI424WR router via cable (and my parents wouldn't like that).

So I'm thinking of getting a wifi extender instead, as my room is quite far away from the wifi router. The wifi still works, but the signal is often only 1-2 bars strong.

Answer (score 1):

The lower band of WiFi signal will bottleneck traffic speed. While you could connect over the higher band, you would see no speed benefit.

IMHO, WiFi extenders never work well if you are interested in speed, unless you spend a fortune. You get what you pay for in terms of range.

Just a suggestion, look into powerline networking.